# Why do these pieces overlap

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I was making this program to make a battleship field full of battleship "pieces" and i made a code which puts the longest piece on the board like this:

```
    public void fieldFiller5(){
    int horizontalOrVertical = random.nextInt(2);
    int starth = random.nextInt(6); // the int has to be below 5
    int startv = random.nextInt(6); 

    for (int j = 0; j<10; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k<10;k++){
            field[j][k]=false;
    }
        if (horizontalOrVertical==0){
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            field[starth+i][startv]= true;  // makes a line of 5 true
            }   
        }
        else{
            for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
            field[starth][startv+i]= true;  // makes a line of 5 true
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

this works perfectly, but now i want to put the second piece onto the field, but i dont want it to overlap the first piece, so i made a check mechanism that checks if all spaces are false and if they aren't it should pick another number and restart the loop, but it doesn't always work too well, here is what it looks like:

```
public void fieldFiller4(){

    for (int k=0; k<2; k++){

        int horizontalOrVertical = random.nextInt(2);
        int starth = random.nextInt(7); // the int has to be below 6
        int startv = random.nextInt(7); 

        if (horizontalOrVertical==0){
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                if ((field[startv+i][starth]==true)){
                starth=random.nextInt(7);
                startv=random.nextInt(7);
                i=0;
                }


            }
            for(int i =0; i<4; i++){
            field[starth+i][startv]= true;  // makes a line of 4 true
            }
        }

        if (horizontalOrVertical==1){
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                if ((field[startv][starth+i]==true)){
                starth=random.nextInt(7);
                startv=random.nextInt(7);
                    i=0;
                }


            }
            for(int i =0; i<4; i++){
                field[starth][startv+i]= true;  // makes a line of 4 true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then i made a printing method which prints it out:

```
public void fieldPrinter(){
        String row = new String("");
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            row = "";
            for(int k = 0; k<10;k++){
                if (field[i][k]==true){
                    row = row+ "X";
                }
                else{
                    row = row+"O";
                }

            }
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    }
}
```

And most of the times it looks fine, somewhat like this:

```
OOOOOOOOOO
OXXXXXOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOXOOO
OOOOOOXOOO
OOOOOOXOOO
OOOOOOXOOO
```

but sometimes it only does the second one, one time and it looks like this:

```
OOOOOXOOOO
OOOOOXOOOO
OOXOOXOOOO
OOXOOXOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
```

and sometimes they overlap and it looks like this:

```
OOOOOOXOOO
OOXOOOXOOO
OOXOOOXOOO
OOXOOXXXXO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOO
```

I can't think of a reason why the program is behaving in such a way, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several places in your code you have your "h" and "v" mixed up.  Specifically, you seem to do `field[startv][starth]` when checking for collisions, but `field[starth][startv]` when filling squares.

Comment: thank you so much, i totally overlooked that. I don't think i could have figured that out myself, i have dyslexia. I changed it and now it works :D